# Hilbert norm and Euclidean distance

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

For real matrix $X$ where $d_{i,j}^2(X)$ indicates the euclidean distance squared between the rows $i,j$ of $X$, if $d_{i,j}^2(X)=||f(X_i.)-f(X_j.)||_H$ then what would the function $f(.)$ be? Is there only one such function? Note that $X_i.$ indicates the row $i$ of $X$ and the norm is the hilbert norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the versors. Given that $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$, then you can use the versors in $\mathbb{R}^N$ which are
$$ e_i = \left [0 ~ 0 \cdot \cdot \cdot 0 ~ 1 ~0  \cdot \cdot \cdot 0 ~ 0 \right]^T$$
where the only "1" is at position $i$.
Then, your $f$ is a $f_i$ defined as follows:
$$ f_i(X) = e_i^T X $$
In this way you obtain your $i$-th row vector.

Finally, you have that $d_{ij}^2(X) = \|f_i(X) - f_j(X)\|_H^2$